Multiple hypothesis testing adjustment when only the number of significant tests is important
We are measuring the effect of a treatment T on a latent outcome variable (specifically, "Discrimination"). We have a number of outcome variables that we think do a reasonable job as proxies for the latent variable, call these outcomes $Y_1,...,Y_N$. We will test the effectiveness of the treatment by running $Y_i=\gamma+\beta_iT$ for each $Y_i\in\{Y_1,...,Y_N\}$. Before collecting the data, we agree that we will consider the treatment effective if it has a positive effect on at least half of these outcomes. For example, if $N=7$, we will call the treatment 'effective' if $\beta_i$ is significantly greater than $0$ for at least 4 outcomes. We do not care in which of the outcomes we find a significant effect, only that this happens in 'at least half' of the regressions.
From my understanding, traditional multiple hypothesis testing adjustments might not be well suited to this situation. They typically answer questions like "What is the probability that the observed significant result for $\beta_1$ is a true positive, considering that 7 tests were conducted on the $\beta_i$'s, and given a significance level of $\alpha = 0.05$?" E.g., a Bonferroni correction such that $\alpha' = \frac{\alpha}{7} \approx 0.007$ seems far too conservative for estimating the probability that that the observed significant, positive result for (any) 4 out of 7 $\beta_i$'s is a true positive.
Can anyone shed some light on this? Specifically:

What adjustments should be made to control for false-positives if 4 out of 7 $\beta_i$'s are significantly greater than 0 at $\alpha = 0.05$ and we wish to conclude that indeed "the treatment has a positive effect on at least half of the outcomes"?
How would the adjustments change if the outcome variables $Y_i$ are correlated?


"What is the probability that the observed significant result for $\beta_1$
is a true positive, considering that 7 tests were conducted on the $\beta_1$'s, and given a significance level of $\alpha =0.05$?" is not what any $p$-value tells (corrected or otherwise). $p$-values can only tell you the probability getting whatever results you've gotten under the null, already assuming the null holds. Similarly, $p$-value significance testing cannot tell you the probability that "the treatment has a positive effect on at least half of the outcomes."
